# "Post to facebook" not displayed on top of all other html elements

Tags: css, facebook, html, facebook-like

On this link (http://kbk-siroki.herokuapp.com/blog/posts/napravljen-update-najnovijih-blog-postova) you can find a blog post with facebook LIKE button.
The problem is when a user clicks on the button "post to facebook" element is hidden below other elements.
Please, can anyone help me solve the problem so that "post to facebook" is completely displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried playing with the z-index?  This can ensure that the sendto box is stacked above all other elements when showing.  I had a look and it seems as if the element has z-index: 1; Try a higher integer and see if that helps.

Comment: Tom, thanks for your reply. The problem is solved. but not compltely. Pop up facebook window now displays as it should, but as you could see from the link - the text "KATEGORIJE" is displayed inside the pop up - and if you could help me on how to display pop up "above" the text KATEGORIJE I would be very grateful